# Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel test on tables larger than 2x2

Tags: cochran-mantel-haenszel

I'm studying use cases for `Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel (CMH)` test. All the examples i've found deal with 2X2 contingency tables. I'm wondering if `CMH` test is applicable for tables larger than 2x2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  You can read some of the theory on [recent extensions of CHH tests by Rayner & Rippon](https://www.mdpi.com/2571-905X/1/1/8)

For 3 dimensional table examples you can look at [Mangiafico's website](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_06.html)

And for doing it in R the [CMHtest function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vcdExtra/versions/0.7-1/topics/CMHtest) is a good start